# convert set to numpy 0-1 array?

Tags: python, numpy, set

I am currently using this method to convert a set of integers (the variable  `words`) to a numpy array:

```
    wordMask = np.asarray( [ int(x not in words)  for x in xrange(0,nwords) ] ).reshape(nwords,1)
```

Here `nwords` can be as large as 10000.

Instead of recomputing `wordMask` every time I could keep it as a separate variable and whenever I add/remove an element from `words` I make the corresponding change to `wordMask`, but I'm wondering if there is a reasonably efficient way to recompute `wordMask`.

Edit: My main concern is that the list comprehension:

```
[ x not in words for x in xrange(0,nwords) ]
```

will be slow, and I'm looking for a faster way to perform that iteration
in the context of creating a `numpy` array.

Comment: What does `words` look like? Why do you need `.reshape()`? Any reason not to us a `numpy.ma.array`?

Comment: `x` is an integer. What is `words`? `x not in words` will just be False for everything right?

Comment: `words` is a `set()` of integers. I could use the `intset` module for better performance I guess, but I'm not doing that at the moment. e.g. `words = set(); a.add(3); a.add(6)`

Comment: @AChampion - I'll look into `numpy.ma.array`. I need a column vector for `wordMask`. AFAIK, `.reshape()` is very performant in that it doesn't make a copy of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take this sample code to begin:

```
import numpy as np

words = set([1, 3, 5, 7, 9])
nwords = len(words)
wordMask = np.asarray([ [int(x not in words)] for x in xrange(0, nwords) ])
```

I changed the `asarray` code to automatically reshape it from the start. Now that you have the word mask, it is simple to update whenever you add or remove a word.

Adding a word:

```
newWord = 4
words.add(newWord)
nwords = len(words)
wordMask = np.concatenate((wordMask, [[1]])) # Resize the mask
if newWord < nwords:                         # Update the mask
    wordMask[newWord][0] = 0
```

Removing a word:

```
oldWord = 3
if oldWord < nwords:                         # Update the mask
    wordMask[oldWord][0] = 1
words.discard(oldWord)
nwords = len(words)
wordMask = np.resize(wordMask, (nwords, 1))  # Resize the mask
```

And there you have it!

I would have personally used a dictionary, as they are easier to deal with. I'm guessing you chose to use NumPy for memory efficiency? NumPy always copies arrays on resize, so the `concatenate()` and `resize()` methods will not necessarily be quick. One option is to set the mask to a fixed size (upper bound) and update any time something changes. That would be much more efficient.

If it is guaranteed that the max size is 10000, then remove the size updates from the above code, and set `nwords` to 10000.

Comment: Thanks - I already know how to keep `wordMask` and `words` in sync. I'm really asking if there is a good way to recompute `wordMask` from `words` on the fly. My main concern is that the list comprehension will be slow.

Comment: If you're only running the list comprehension once, what is your concern for speed? 10000 will run quite quickly either way.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [`numpy.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html). Here's an example usage:

```
>>> nwords = 10
>>> words = {1, 5, 3, 8, 6}
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.bincount(list(s), minlength=nwords)  # words present
array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0])
>>> 1 - numpy.bincount(list(s), minlength=nwords)  # words absent
array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1])
```

Unfortunately this still involves a Python-level iteration over the elements of `s` (implicit in the `list` call). I couldn't find a quicker way to get NumPy to interpret the set here than converting it to a `list` first.

Some timings (with Python 3.6, NumPy 1.13.1) show that this solution is faster, but not incredibly so:

```
In [13]: %timeit numpy.asarray( [ int(x not in words)  for x in range(0,nwords) ] )
6.17 µs ± 25.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [14]: %timeit 1 - numpy.bincount(list(s), minlength=nwords)
3.97 µs ± 228 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```